# How to intercept an AJAX call and change the target host before it is sent

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

To intercept native ajax calls I found the following snippet which works fine

```
(function(XHR) {
    "use strict";

    var open = XHR.prototype.open;
    var send = XHR.prototype.send;

    XHR.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
        this._url = url;
        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    };

    XHR.prototype.send = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        var oldOnReadyStateChange;
        var url = this._url;
        console.log(url);

        function onReadyStateChange() {
            if(self.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
                /* This is where you can put code that you want to execute post-complete*/
                /* URL is kept in this._url */
            }

            if(oldOnReadyStateChange) {
                oldOnReadyStateChange();
            }
        }

        /* Set xhr.noIntercept to true to disable the interceptor for a particular call */
        if(!this.noIntercept) {            
            if(this.addEventListener) {
                this.addEventListener("readystatechange", onReadyStateChange, false);
            } else {
                oldOnReadyStateChange = this.onreadystatechange; 
                this.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChange;
            }
        }

        send.call(this, data);
    }
})(XMLHttpRequest);
```

But what I want to do is, change the target host, so instead of having these ajax request run on the current website, I want to direct them to another site instead.

I tried `this.setRequestHeader('Host', 'example.com');`, but I received an error in the console telling me I'm trying to set a forbidden header.

I could in fact make another ajax request, but it would be much more convenient for me to just switch hosts.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the `beforeSend` method of ajax?

Comment: @AliSajid Are you talking about jQuery's AJAX beforeSend? If so, it only intercepts AJAX calls made with jQuery so it does not serve my purpose. Otherwise I do not know of any method named beforeSend for the native XHR.